# SSH: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: macos, ssh, sshd, ssh-keys

Here's the setup, I have four machines:

- *A*: An Ubuntu box, acting as the ssh client;
- *B*: An iMac under El Capitan (OS X 10.11), the ssh server I want to connect to;
- *C*: Another iMac under Mavericks (OS X 10.9);
- *D*: A Synology NAS (DSM 5.2);

From *A* I can connect to *C* and *D*. From *C* and *D* I can connect to *B*. But when I try to connect to *B* from *A* I get the following messages:

On *A* (with `-vvv` option):

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 2a01:********* [2a01:*********] port22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
ebug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

On *B*:

```
sshd[7215]: error: BSM audit: getaddrinfo failed for UNKNOWN: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
sshd[7215]: Could not write ident string to UNKNOWN
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.1681EC73-750F-45A5-998D-B54A0BBE893E[7215]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a firewall issue. In order to connect through ssh you have to allow `launchd`, not `sshd`, to accept incoming connexions.

Comment: How do I do. this

Comment: Depends on the firewall software you are using (it’s not a system feature). You need to setup a rule that allows incoming connexion for launchd process.